# What will a search committee do when a letter writer does not respond?

Tags: recommendation-letter, job-search

I have submitted my applications for faculty positions, and one of my recommenders ask that I make sure their letters show "received" in the application portals.

Some of the applications provide this level of information, but others do not show whether a letter has been received (or even solicited).

In the case that a letter is solicited, but the recommender does not respond (misses the email, forgets, etc.), what is the typical course of action taken by a search committee? Will they reach out to the applicant, so that I can remind my recommender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A committee will have its own procedures, but likely they will try to reach the applicant and the recommender. In extreme cases they might need to make a decision with limited information, but will hesitate to do so and use what means are available to complete the application.

When you ask someone to write you a letter it is probably a good idea to ask them to ping you when it is sent. They might or not, but it is a simple enough thing.

Relax. Things normally work as intended.